# Fastest way to eval array of math expressions

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I have an array with Sympy expressions like this:

```py
np.Array([A + B, C + D - 2.0*E + 10, ...])
```

Expressions can change and execution time really matters here.
I have the values for A, B, C, D ... in a dictionary. Values are iterables, like `A = [1,2,3,4]`.

What is the fastest way to evaluate each expression?
Which is faster, eval or lambify? Is there a vectorized way to do this?

Comment: If you're doing straightforward math with known values, why use Sympy at all?

Comment: "Is there a vectorized way to do this?" Do you have A, B, C, D as NumPy arrays? If so, lambdify can use NumPy vectorization.

Comment: You provided too little details for us to give a proper answer. However, if you go down the `lambdify` route, I suggest changing your `np.Array` of equation with sympy's `Array`, so that you call `lambdify` only once "per cycle", instead of `n` times per cycle (one lambdify call for each equation). This definitely saves some time, especially if you have many equations...

Comment: Pl check my answer now. I've edited my previous answer

Comment: I'm using Sympy because those are symbolic solutions to other equations. Sympy cannot handle those kinds of values, so I cannot replace the values before solving

Comment: mixing sympy and numpy often doesn't work.  A list is better for holding symbols and expressions.  `lambdify` can convert expressions into numeric functions, though it doesn't always work.  `help(fun)` can show the generated code,

Comment: Staying with `sympy` you can `subs` in numeric values for symbols.  There are various ways of asking `sympy` to give numeric solutions.  Often it uses `mpmath` to do that numeric work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the concept called dynamic variable and even without numpy.

```
#Change the dictionary keys and values according to your requirement
dct = {'A':[1,2,3,4], 'B':[3,4,2,1], 'C':[5,3,1,2], 'D':[6,2,7,5], 'E':[2,4,2,1]}

new_list = []

##iterate over the length of each list
for i in range(4):

    #Iterate over dct
    for key,value in dct.items():
    
        #make keys as variable names
        dynvar = key
    
        #make the values as variable-values
        globals()[dynvar] = value[i]
    
    #Change the expressions according to your requirement
    x = [A + B, C + D - 2.0*E + 10, D*E]
    new_list.append(x)
print(new_list) 
#Output: [[4, 17.0, 12, 1], [6, 7.0, 8, 16], [5, 14.0, 14, 9], [5, 15.0, 5, 4]]
```

Comment: I've edited my answer for nested iteration. Pl check

Comment: While using `globals` like this works, it isn't encouraged (not 'pythonic')